# Was SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION bugged on tablets?

Tags: android

It's documented that [`View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION` does not hide the system bar on tablets](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.0.html#SystemUI).  I'm setting it unconditionally because I want to use it on phones, and I don't know of any reliable way to test whether the device is a phone or tablet.

The newest tablet I have to test on is a Lenovo A2107A running 4.0.4.  This tablet seems to consume the touch event that would show the navigation bar, even though it's not actually hidden.  In other words, it ignores the first touch on every activity.

**Is this a bug, and if so, when was it fixed?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It behaves as expected if used in conjunction with `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE`.